# Swing app with security manager causing strange GUI-refresh issues

Tags: java, swing, awt, securitymanager

I have a Swing app (residing in an executable, signed jar) that is a client. The app also connects to a server. When certain conditions are met, I perform a refresh of the GUI (more specifically, delete all nodes of a `JTree` and then repopulate it). When I run this client as-is (i.e., without a security manager and without residing in an executable, signed JAR), the tree refreshes and updates without any issue.

However, when I package my client as a signed JAR (with the appropriate policy file), I get refresh issues. When the app starts up, I my `JTree` is not expanded. When I click it once, it looks like it has expanded, but the child nodes do not show. I have to click it twice after that for the nodes to show. Also, when I perform a refresh (deleting all nodes and then repopulating), the UI doesn't refresh appropriately. I (again) have to click the root-node twice to refresh the GUI.

I tried adding AWT permissions to the policy file, but that didn't help (I wasn't seeing any permission-violations in the first place, but I thought I'd try). I even tried giving the JAR all permissions. That didn't seem to help either. What could be causing this?

The code that performs the refresh is as follows:

```
private void buildTree() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    setVisible(false);
    tree.removeTreeWillExpandListener(this);
    tree.removeTreeSelectionListener(this);

    DefaultTreeModel treeModel = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) treeModel.getRoot();
    root.removeAllChildren();

    root.setUserObject(base);

    Book[] bookArray = remoteLibraryService.getAllBooks();
    TreeBuilderService.buildTree(root, bookArray);
    treeModel.reload();

    for(int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
        tree.expandRow(i);
    }

    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
    tree.addTreeWillExpandListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

The code that populates the tree (showing just the relevant snippet):

```
categoryNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(book.getGenre());
root.add(categoryNode);
```

This probably isn't a deal-breaker as far as the assignment is concerned, but it is really bothering me; I'd like to figure out what's causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [*Initial Threads*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), Swing GUI components must be created on the event dispatch thread. Empirically, `JTree` is particularly susceptible to fail when manipulated from another thread. The `SecurityManager` is probably adventitious; any change in timing, even changing platforms, may expose the flaw.

Comment: Thanks! This is interesting. I was not aware of it. I tried doing this (calling `buildTree()` with `invokeAndWait`), but I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` on `LibraryClient$1`.

Comment: Never mind. I was running it from a jar and I forgot to add the inner class to the jar. Thanks! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Well you are doing IO in the GUI refresh cycle, so the GUI thread might well be blocked/stalled as a result.
Instead consider using a SwingWorker and asynchronous population of the Tree through its API.